# Packet capture using winpcap on ppp device

Tags: libpcap, winpcap, ppp

When I make a call to get network interfaces' name using winpcap I get all devices name but I am not getting ppp device(my 3g usb stick).
How can I capture packets coming from this device?

I am working on windows vista.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as indicated by [question 5](http://www.winpcap.org/misc/faq.htm#Q-5) in the [WinPcap FAQ](http://www.winpcap.org/misc/faq.htm), that's not supported on Windows Vista or Windows 7.